# Bugzilla - How to setup MTA that will receive Gmail to create bugs

Tags: email, bugzilla, email-server

I have been looking for a while on setting up an MTA for bugzilla to receive bugs via email and am not really seeing any detailed guides.

Currently I am using gmail as the outbound smtp for messages, but I do not have a solution for the receiving of emails as bugs.

I am assuming I would setup an MTA and it would grab down the emails and then bugzilla would read them somehow.

I am unsure of this process/a solution for this; Any detailed help or direction would be great.

Distro: Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Please edit to show the actual question being asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an external server to actually receive the mail, you can use `fetchmail` to collect the mail via POP3 or IMAP from GMail and feed it into your local postfix installation and then use `procmail` via a `.forward` file to feed it into Bugzilla's `email_in.pl`.

[This](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Bugzilla_Email) is a guide outlining the steps for Gentoo Linux, but it should be easy to adapt to the system of your choice.

I am not sure how `email_in.pl` actually works, but it might be possible to use it as an MDA for fetchmail directly, so you don't need a full postfix configuration. This is the method I use e.g. for my RT installations.

A typical `fetchmailrc` file would look similar to the following:

```
poll mailserver.com proto pop3: 
username username password 12345  mda "/path/to/email_in.pl"
```

Comment: Thank you for some guidance. I am currently got fetchmail setup and seeing the messages in the gmail account. So at least I feel like I am moving in some sort of direction. I will let you know how it turns out.